# SpreadhsheetGear to read bulk excel file

Tags: c#, .net, spreadsheetgear

I want to read a bulk excel file using SpreadhsheetGear

```
    public ValueFormulaSet ReadData(string sheetName, string address)
    {
        var wrksh = this.Workbook.Worksheets[sheetName];

        var range = wrksh.Range[address];

        var result = new ValueFormulaSet();

        result.RowCount = range.RowCount;

        result.Values = (object[,])range.Value;

        result.Formulas = (object[,])GetFormulas(range);

        return result;
    }
```

I am wondering that this approach will read the whole data and populate it in the `result.Values`
as I want to use bulk data file, this approach may consume much memory.

Is there any other way by which I can improve the approach for better memory optimization ?

I don't know how SpreadhsheetGear handles bulk files.
I am looking for some lazy loading approach by which I can do some buffering,
or I wish to do something like implementing `IDataReader` and use `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync Method (IDataReader)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SpreadsheetGear** loads the whole excel file entirely.
I confirmed this thing with their Technical support guys, they replied me

> "our product is a full-fledged spreadsheet component with a
>   calculation engine and rich workbook manipulation capabilities. 
>   Because of this, we must load an Excel file in its entirety—unlike
>   other third-party spreadsheet products out there which might be able
>   to get away with only partially loading parts of the file here or
>   there"

SpreadsheetGear is good for the cases where there is requirement to perform some calculations and workbook manipulation.
My requirement is just to import data from bulk excel files so I switched to **OLE DB** and used SQLBulkCopy class with the data reader.